# How to react to this RPC error as a dev: Node is behind by 166 slots

Tags: transactions, rpc, error, sendtransactionerror

I was getting this error when sending a transaction to the RPC:

```
Transaction failed: RPC response error -32005: Node is behind by 166 slots
```

Why does this happen?
How should we react to this error? Shall we simply retry after a delay?

Comment: "react" in what role?  are you the node operator or simply querying it as a dev?

Comment: Querying it as a dev

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This means the RPC node you are using can't keep up with leader for some reason (network, load surge, etc).

You can't do anything about it, just wait until it catches up, or use another RPC to send your request.

Comment: You can also get a node provider that takes care of this https://solana.com/rpc , eg https://chainstack.com/protocols/solana/

Answer (score 2):

@vladyslav-melnychenko's answer is correct with regard to cause.  However if you know you're using a load-balanced RPC endpoint, it is typically okay to retry the operation at a reasonable rate until it succeeds.  The delinquent backend will either catch up or be removed from the pool.  Keep in mind that if you've already successfully queried some time-sensitive information, like a recent blockhash, you may need to retry operations besides the one that actually failed as well